# SQL - no rows selected after inner join - I don't get it

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Ok here are my two tables I'm trying to do a join on, using ORACLE:

FOURNISSEUR

[image: FOURNISSEUR]

TABLE4

[image: table4]

And I'm sorry for copying pictures but I'm having a hard time copying tables from MYSQLPLUS..

I'm trying to do a join on NF but it doesn't seem to work... what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT fournisseur.NF,fournisseur.NomF
FROM fournisseur
INNER JOIN table4
ON fournisseur.NF=table4.NF
ORDER BY fournisseur.NF;
```

And yeah I feel stupid..

Comment: I see no issue:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2262/2/0

Comment: Try wrapping each of your `JOIN` criteria with `TRIM()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the NF column in the fournisseur table have *spaces* after the values?

The column heading for fournisseur.NF looks *really wide* and appears to be displaying a `VARCHAR2(20)` (or `CHAR(20)`; but see below) column which could also mean there is extra white-space.

Try trimming the values. e.g.

```
ON TRIM(fournisseur.NF) = table4.NF
```

If this indeed works, then I'd look into using `CHAR(2)`, which is hopefully the same type as table4.NF, for fournisseur.NF which would avoid this issue simply by not allowing the extra spaces to begin with.

Since filler spaces on the end of a `CHAR(n)` field "don't mean anything" then using `CHAR(n)` types throughout would also remove the observed issue.

---

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e634/1), modified from Coat CO's comment, which shows lack-of-join behavior when there are extra spaces in a `VARCHAR2(n)` column.